# Bounded operator has graph closed.

Tags: operator-theory

[image]

Hello. I am reviewing the concepts of closed operators and the following questions have come up.

**Question 1.** in the definition of invertible operator. Operator $A$ doesn't necessarily have to be bounded, right?

**Question 2**. Why any bounded operator is closed? In the image, it is mentioned that it is due to the closed graph theorem, but this theorem only proves that if an operator is closed, then it is bounded but not the reciprocal. I have only:

If $A:D(A)\subset X\to Y$ is bounded and $x_n\to x,\, Ax_n\to y$, with $x\in X,\, y\in Y, (x_n)\subset D(A)$ then $\left\|Ax-y\right\|_{Y}\leq \left\|A(x-x_n)\right\|_{Y}+\left\|Ax_n-y\right\|_{Y}\leq \left\|x_n-x\right\|_{X}+\left\|Tx_n-y\right\|_{Y}\to 0$ therefore $Ax=y$, but, why $x\in D(A)$?

add: $X$ Banach space.

Comment: You did not mention what $X$ is . Is it comeplete? That fact is of atmost importance for this question.

Comment: X is a Banach space

Comment: $X$ Banach space and $\left\{x_n\right\}\subset D(A)$ with $x_n\to x$ in $X$ implies $x\in D(A)$?

Comment: The fact that a bouded opeator has close graph is being applied by the author to $A^{-1}$, not to $A$. The domain of $A^{-1}$ is the whole space. So your question does not arise.

Comment: a question. $A^{-1}:X\to D(A)$ is bounded if and only if $\left\|A^{-1}x\right\|_{X}\leq C\left\|x\right\|_{X}$ for all $x\in X$, right?
I ask this because I often get confused with $\left\|A^{-1}x\right\|_{D(A)}\leq C\left\|x\right\|_{X}$ for all $x\in X$

Comment: There is no difference between $\|A^{-1}x\|_{D(A)}$ and $||A^{-1}x\|_X$.

Comment: ok, but why the autor says "any bounded operator has a closed graph"?

Comment: I think the author considers the graph as a subset of $D(A) \times X$, not as a subset of $X \times X$. If this is the case then it is true that boundedness of $T$ implies closedness of its graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Questions 1. Right. For example, let $X=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, then $A(\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty)= (\{nx_n\}_n)$ has bounded inverse $A(\{x_n\})=\{\frac{x_n}{n}\}$. In fact, according to the result, any injective bounded operator $T: X\rightarrow X$ with dense image is the inverse of some not necessarily bounded operator.
- Question 2. In this particular case, due to $AA^{-1}y=y$ for all $y\in X$, $A^{-1}$ at least can be applied to any vector $y\in X$, hence $D(A^{-1})=X$. But when people say "bounded operator $A$", then $D(A)=X$ is usually implicitly assumed. Indeed, since $D(A)$ is dense, and $A$ is bounded, there is a unique way to extend $A$ to be a bounded operator on $X$, so the assumption doesn't hurt.